# How can i introduce my own stickers in my own app developmented with aviary SDK?

Tags: android, aviary

I see in Aviary documentation that existe "Custom Content" (https://developers.aviary.com/content) but don't said how i have to do for introduce it in the android app that i'm developing.

Where can i found documentation about this?

Thanks